# grep start and end time from log file- AIX

Tags: awk, sed, grep, aix

Log file looks something like below

**Process Beginning -  2016-04-02-00.36.13**

Putting Files To daADadD for 
File will move to /sadafJJHFASJFFASJ/

Extract Files :-/ASFDSHAF_**ABC_2016-04-02.csv**
/ASFDSHAF_ABC.2016-04-02.csv /
ASFDSHAF_ABC.2016-04-02.csv /ASFDSHAF_**ABC.2016-04-02.csv** /

**Process Ending -  2016-04-02-00.36.36**

**Process Beginning -  2016-04-02-10.01.20**

Putting Files To daADadD for 
File will move to /sadafJJHFASJFFASJ/

Extract Files :-/sdshsdhsh_**cvb.2016-04-02.csv**
/sdshsdhsh_cvb.2016-04-02.csv /sdshsdhsh_cvb.2016-04-02.csv

**Process Ending -  2016-04-02-10.01.21**

There is multiple entries of pattern / Process Beginning -  2016-04-02/ /Process Ending -  2016-04-02/
how do I find entry or block which has pattern /ABC_2016-04-02.csv/ in between

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output given that input. If you need to search for some pattern in a block, make sure to include both blocks that do AND blocks that don't match that pattern in your sample input/output.

Comment: Again (and for the last time) - **Edit your question to show the expected output given that input**. Also use the `{}` editor button to make your blocks of data or code appear as-is and get rid of any formatting you've tried to add (e.g. making parts bold with `**`s). Make your input and output appear in your question the same as they do in your real files so we can test a potential solution against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sed (at least with GNU sed 4, sorry no AIX sed to test with):

```
# read complete block into hold space
/Process Beginning/,/Process Ending/ {
    H
}

# "test" for csvfile in the block
/Process Ending/ {
    # get hold space (i.e. complete block)
    x 
    # if s did a "substition" (i.e. csvfile occured in the block): print
    s/ASFDSHAF_ABC.2016-04-02.csv/&/p
    # clear hold space for next block
    s/.*// 
    h
}
```

Say your log file is `grplog.log` and the script is `grplog.sed` then run the script like this: `sed -n -f grplog.sed grplog.log`.

**Explanation:**

- The script reads all lines in your processing block into the hold space in the first part.
- The second part triggered on the `Process Ending` line uses the `p` flag of the `s` command: if a substitution was made, print the new pattern space. Due to the use of `&` old and new pattern space are the same.

Comment: will it work when we multiple occurrence for process Beginning and ending??

Comment: @Sushma Please provide example lines from your log file for testing.

Comment: @Sushma What do you mean by *multiple occurrence for process Beginning and ending*? Several blocks? I tested the script with several blocks. If it does not work for you, please edit the question and provide more lines in the example.

Comment: Could you please give me full scipt

Comment: @SushmaBhandary the script `grplog.sed` is what is in the gray area in my answer. I use sed version 4.2.2 on Linux and for me the script seems to work.  After your edit, I replaced csvfile in line 11 with your new filename.